# Open Source chart generation software from database or csv files

Tags: database, charts

Is anybody aware of an Open Source (or even non OS) piece of software for generating on the fly charts from a database or csv files? ideally web based.

A typical use case would be to set up a datastore (like in GeoSever for instance) with database + table, select a chart type and plot a column vs another (or whatever makes sense) + with some aggregate functions.

Comment: I voted for "too broad".

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Diego, I get your point. My question is unfortunately of that type and may be I should delete it. In terms of what has been done, I have pretty much everything I need to start coding such a functionality, but before starting with it, I wanted to make sure there wasn't some existing code base I could make use of.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, is not my point, but the Stackoverflow.com rules, you could try to maintain it open and wait as it has a response.

Answer (score 0):

try "R" http://www.r-project.org/ any kind of chart, any kind of data, generates a png or jpg for your web page.